# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError handling 14 data from Camera

Tags: android, crash, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am making and an Audit app where I have to collect yes/no from radio button and images of 14 checkpoints.

The app is working fine in my device which has Android 10 device but when testing on some devices like in some Nougat device after collecting 4-6 images in any random manner and show them on respective Imageview and collect Byte[] in String variable the app crashes no error in log also(NOW FOUND it through Debugger see below). have a look at the code of camera. the app crashed after clicking the photo when it returns back to activity.

```
 public void ClickImageFromCamera(String code) {


        Intent CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        String img_Decodable_Str = String.valueOf(destination);
        Log.e("img fromCam", String.valueOf(destination));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", destination);
            CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(destination);
            CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        }
        CamIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(CamIntent, Integer.parseInt(code));






    }
```

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("Request code", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        Log.e("ResultCode ", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        if (requestCode == 50) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(50);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(50);
                }


            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }else {
            // failed to capture image
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(51);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(51);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 52) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(52);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(52);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 53) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(53);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(53);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 54) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(54);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(54);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 55) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(55);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(55);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 56) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(56);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(56);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 57) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(57);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(57);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 58) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(58);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(58);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 59) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(59);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(59);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 60) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(60);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(60);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 61) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(61);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(61);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 62) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(62);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(62);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == 63) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    //this is above marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage(63);
                } else {
                    //this is below marshmellow
                    previewCapturedImage1(63);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image

            }

        }


    }
```

```
 public void previewCapturedImage(int code) {

        try {



            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            // ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // image_stream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(sendUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


            int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, nh, true);
            scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
           /* byte[] imageBytes1 = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes1, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            Log.e("encode",encoded);*/
            Log.e("Original   dimensions", bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
            Log.e("Compressed dimensions", scaled.getWidth() + " " + scaled.getHeight());
            /*int size = scaled.getRowBytes() * scaled.getHeight();
            Log.e("size", String.valueOf(size));
            java.nio.ByteBuffer b = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

            scaled.copyPixelsToBuffer(b);
 byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            Log.e("bytes", String.valueOf(bytes));
*/

            if(code ==50) {
                imageCode1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode1);
                set_img_fascia.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==51) {
                imageCode2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode2);
                set_img_lollypop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==52) {
                imageCode3 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode3);
                set_img_ATM_Count.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==53) {
                imageCode4 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode4);
                set_img_ATM_Cooling.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==54) {
                imageCode5 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode5);
                set_img_ATM_Backroom_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==55) {
                imageCode6 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode6);
                set_img_ups_room.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==56) {
                imageCode7 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode7);
                set_img_Branch_Shutter_Damaged.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==57) {
                imageCode8 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode8);
                set_img_Branch_Round_Taken.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==58) {
                imageCode9 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode9);
                set_img_AC_ODU_Copper_Intact.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==59) {
                imageCode10 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode10);
                set_img_Any_Water_Logging_Vincinity.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==60) {
                imageCode11 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode11);
                set_img_FE_Room_Available.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==61) {
                imageCode12 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode12);
                set_img_DG_Door_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==62) {
                imageCode13 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode13);
                set_img_Other_Obsevation.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==63) {
                imageCode14 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode14);
                set_img_Damage_ATM_lobby.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
/*
//decode base64 string to image
            imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageCode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
            set_img_trainy.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);*/

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void previewCapturedImage1(int code) {

        try {
            //encode base64 string to image
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(),
                    options);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            // byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            //imageCode = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            // Log.e("image_code", imageCode);

            if(code ==50) {
                imageCode1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode1);
                set_img_fascia.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==51) {
                imageCode2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode2);
                set_img_lollypop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==52) {
                imageCode3 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode3);
                set_img_ATM_Count.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==53) {
                imageCode4 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode4);
                set_img_ATM_Cooling.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==54) {
                imageCode5 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode5);
                set_img_ATM_Backroom_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==55) {
                imageCode6 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode6);
                set_img_ups_room.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==56) {
                imageCode7 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode7);
                set_img_Branch_Shutter_Damaged.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==57) {
                imageCode8 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode8);
                set_img_Branch_Round_Taken.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==58) {
                imageCode9 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode9);
                set_img_AC_ODU_Copper_Intact.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==59) {
                imageCode10 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode10);
                set_img_Any_Water_Logging_Vincinity.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==60) {
                imageCode11 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode11);
                set_img_FE_Room_Available.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==61) {
                imageCode12 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode12);
                set_img_DG_Door_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==62) {
                imageCode13 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode13);
                set_img_Other_Obsevation.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==63) {
                imageCode14 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode14);
                set_img_Damage_ATM_lobby.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
 public void previewCapturedImage1(int code) {

        try {
            //encode base64 string to image
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(),
                    options);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            // byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            //imageCode = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            // Log.e("image_code", imageCode);

            if(code ==50) {
                imageCode1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode1);
                set_img_fascia.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==51) {
                imageCode2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode2);
                set_img_lollypop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==52) {
                imageCode3 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode3);
                set_img_ATM_Count.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==53) {
                imageCode4 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode4);
                set_img_ATM_Cooling.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==54) {
                imageCode5 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode5);
                set_img_ATM_Backroom_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==55) {
                imageCode6 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode6);
                set_img_ups_room.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==56) {
                imageCode7 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode7);
                set_img_Branch_Shutter_Damaged.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==57) {
                imageCode8 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode8);
                set_img_Branch_Round_Taken.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==58) {
                imageCode9 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode9);
                set_img_AC_ODU_Copper_Intact.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==59) {
                imageCode10 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode10);
                set_img_Any_Water_Logging_Vincinity.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==60) {
                imageCode11 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode11);
                set_img_FE_Room_Available.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==61) {
                imageCode12 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode12);
                set_img_DG_Door_Locked.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==62) {
                imageCode13 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode13);
                set_img_Other_Obsevation.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            if(code ==63) {
                imageCode14 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode14);
                set_img_Damage_ATM_lobby.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

found Error in Debugger

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.field_officer, PID: 15547
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 8MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:681)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:657)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:701)
        at com.field_officer.Fragment.ICICI_report_Static_Fragment.previewCapturedImage(ICICI_report_Static_Fragment.java:794)
        at com.field_officer.Fragment.ICICI_report_Static_Fragment.onActivityResult(ICICI_report_Static_Fragment.java:1506)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
        at com.field_officer.HomeActivity.onActivityResult(HomeActivity.java:740)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6950)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1585)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
```

Comment: _"the app crashes no error in log also."_ Are you sure? _"the app crashed after clicking the photo when it returns back to activity."_ You could then debug the `onActivityResult()` method step by step and see what exactly crashes and what are the variable values i.e. is something `null` for example.

Comment: Ok found Error in Debugger 
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 8MB until OOM

Comment: Sounds like a problem when editing large bitmaps. The Android documentation might provide some relevant hints on [managing bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/).

Comment: `Camera Intent Crashes in some Device` If it was the intent then you should have posted only that code. But it seems that it is only after onActivityResult is invoked and you executing all kind of code. Please update your subject with the real problem.

Comment: You have much too much possibilities in onActivityResult. One would have been enough. Please remove all others. ANd why previewCapturedImage an previewCapturedImage2 ? Post only the one that causes the problem. Post a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it.

```
            int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, nh, true);
            scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

         
            Log.e("Original   dimensions", bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
            Log.e("Compressed dimensions", scaled.getWidth() + " " + scaled.getHeight());
              Log.e("bytes", String.valueOf(bytes));

          bitmap =null;
            if(code ==50) {
                imageCode1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode1);
                set_img_fascia.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            }
            if(code ==51) {
                imageCode2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.e("image1", imageCode2);
                set_img_lollypop.setImageBitmap(scaled);

...So on
```